# Inclusion of license notice in managed package hosted on AppExchange

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, visualforce-component, appexchange

We have a managed package hosted on AppExchange. We would like to include Mutli-select picklist component provided here (https://github.com/metadaddy/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist) in our package.

However, there is a license notice mentioned README file and we are not sure about satisfying all the conditions mentioned in the notice.
Currently, we have included the license notice as comment in all the components of the Multi-select picklist plug-in.

Do we need to include that anywhere else to satisfy all the conditions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably ask @metadaddy about that. I've mentioned him so he can respond here directly.